# I can't call an array from a class

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

What I want is count letters of each word. Then list it with arrays. I wrote a method in a class called WordLengths and when I try to call it. I get [4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4] instead of [4, 2, 6, 5] Can you help?

```
public class quiz3 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       String s;
       s = "This is really easy.";
       System.out.print(Arrays.toString(WordLengths.getArrayList(s) + " "));//The line with the problem.
   }
}


public class WordLengths {   

    private String s;

    public WordLengths(String s) {
         this.s = s;
    }

    public static int[] getArrayList(String s) {
       int i, x, j;
       x = 0;
       char c;
       int[] list = new int[10];
       for (i = 0; i <= s.length() - 1; i++) {
           c = s.charAt(i);
           if (c == ' ' ) {
               for(j = 0; j <= list.length - 1; j++) {
                  if(list[j] == 0) {
                      list[j] = x;
                  }
               } 
               x = 0;
          } else if (i == s.length() - 1) {
              x++;
              for(j = 0; j <= list.length - 1; j++) {
                  if(list[j] == 0) {
                      list[j] = x;
                  }
              }
              x = 0;
          } else 
          x++;
      }
      return list;
  }
}
```

Comment: `WordLengths.getArrayList(s) + " "` is a String, which cannot be an argument for `Arrays.toString`

Comment: Check the perenthesis here `System.out.print(Arrays.toString(WordLengths.getArrayList(s) + " "));`. It will be `Arrays.toStrin(int[] + " ")`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the concatenated string from the argument:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(WordLengths.getArrayList(s)));
```

The argument `WordLengths.getArrayList(s) + " "` is of type string.

Comment: Yes it solved the problem. Thanks. Can you look at the output problem?

Answer (score 2):

`WordLengths.getArrayList(s) + " "` is a String.

Remove `+ " "` so the type is the one of `WordLengths.getArrayList(s)`, which is`int[]`.

Comment: Can you look at the output problem?

Answer (score 0):

You know, you can convert a String into an array of Characters and just pull the length property of that array as the number of characters. I would try that.

```
String str = "testString";
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
System.out.println("Word Length : " + charArray.length);
```

Comment: Can you look at the output problem?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your output problem.

- split the string into words
- create a array for the lengths
- store the lenght of each word

  ```
  public static int[] getArrayList(String s) {
      String[] words = s.split("\\s");
      int[] list = new int[words.length];
      for (int wordIdx = 0; wordIdx < words.length; wordIdx++) {
          list[wordIdx] = words[wordIdx].length();
      }
      return list;
  }
  ```